# Wordpress list all posts (excerpt) php loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress template and I now need some code that creates a loop to show all posts but not full posts, just excerpts.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to generate the excerpt into the loop:

```
<?php
    if(have_posts())
    {
        while(have_posts())
        {
            the_post();

            the_excerpt();
        }
    }
?>
```

The above will generate only the excerpt of the posts. If you need extra options like post title, date, author and more you have to read the WordPress codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page

You can read more by following the link given by markratledge below.

Comment: This is very strange... I've got 3 posts and only 1 is being listed and they are all published :o/

Comment: I don't realy know now what's going wrong :) All of the posts have the same excerpt or diferent ?

Comment: What's wrong with it ? I've got it from wordpress theme twentyeleven ?? :?

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need to know - with examples - is here: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

The most basic loop is

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
?>
```

and you want to use `the_excerpt()` instead of `the_content()` See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt